# Create a new table on insert in another table Azure Sql UWP Apps

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am creating an app where you can create news articles and post them, then people can comment on the article.

I have created an Azure App Service Mobile App, that connects me to table Articles in my azure sql database.

What I want is, when I insert an item into the Articles table, I want  it to automatically create another table that will hold comments for that item that I inserted into the Articles table.

Is there a way to do it programmatically or I need to do it using sql, and if so, how ?

I am using a .NET backend (C#) and it is a UWP (windows 10) app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, not possible without restarting the server (to adjust the models, etc.) and inadvisable (due to explosion of tables you have to do).

Instead, create a Comments table and have an ArticleId that refers to the article that is being commented on.  You can even link the Article with the comments using normal Entity Framework mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much, I guess I have to create a comments table and store all of them there. Just for interest sake, as you said I can link Article with the comments using Entity Framework mechanism, how would I do that?

Comment: Check out this tutorial:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx - particularly with reference to foreign keys.